# Performance loading a class from an external website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am loading the content (the number / price) of a div class .price from an external website so I can then compare it with my own price.

I haveused this which works but really slows down the speed of my page loading:

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="price">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];

?>
```

Is this just the problem of loading from an external site or is there a way to load content faster or a more efficient way?

I have tried this:

```
$('#price').load('https://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx .price');
```

Does it need to be an ID for the above to work? Or javascript can't be from an external site?

Thanks!

Comment: Load the remote URL directly in your browser.  Does it take a while to load?  If so, there's your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is set up a cron job that gets the prices from the external web-site and stores them in your database. Depending on how frequently the prices change, you can do that once a day, multiple times per hour, etc.

Then you can get the external price from your own database and compare it to your own price without having to connect to the external web-site.

Comment: I'll have a look at this now, thanks for the response!